# How to get help in R?

Tags: r, r-faq

What is the possible documentation available for R package? For example I try to understand `sp` package.

In addition to `help(sp)`, what are the other functions for searching through help and documentation?

Comment: The most immediate help for that package would come from `help(pac=sp)` which should bring up the Index page.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

#### Getting help on a function that you know the name of

Use [`?`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/Question) or, equivalently, [`help`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/help).

```
?mean
help(mean) # same
```

For non-standard names use [quotes](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/Quotes) or backquotes; see [An Introduction to R: Getting help with functions and features](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Getting-help):

> For a feature specified by special characters, the argument must be enclosed in double or single quotes, making it a “character string”: This is also necessary for a few words with syntactic meaning including `if`, `for` and `function`."

```
?`if`
?"if"       # same
help("if")  # same
```

There are also help pages for datasets, general topics and some packages.

```
?iris
?Syntax
?lubridate
```

Use the [`example`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/example) function to see examples of how to use it.

```
example(paste)
example(`for`)
```

The [`demo`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/demo) function gives longer demonstrations of how to use a function.

```
demo()                           # all demos in loaded pkgs
demo(package = .packages(all.available = TRUE)) # all demos
demo(plotmath)
demo(graphics)
```

---

#### Finding a function that you don't know the name of

Use `??` or, equivalently, [`help.search`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/help.search).

```
??regression
help.search("regression")
```

Again, non-standard names and phrases need to be quoted.

```
??"logistic regression"
```

[`apropos`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/apropos) finds functions and variables in the current session-space (but not in installed but not-loaded packages) that match a regular expression.

```
apropos("z$") # all fns ending with "z"
```

[`rseek.org`](http://rseek.org) is an R search engine with a [Firefox plugin](http://mycroftproject.com/search-engines.html?name=rseek.org).

[`RSiteSearch`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/RSiteSearch) searches several sites directly from R.

[`findFn`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sos/docs/findFn) in `sos` wraps `RSiteSearch` returning the results as a HTML table.

```
RSiteSearch("logistic regression")

library(sos)
findFn("logistic regression")
```

---

#### Finding packages

[`available.packages`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/available.packages) tells you all the packages that are available in the repositories that you set via [`setRepositories`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/setRepositories).  [`installed.packages`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/installed.packages) tells you all the packages that you have installed in all the libraries specified in [`.libPaths`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/.libPaths).  [`library`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/library) (without any arguments) is similar, returning the names and tag-line of installed packages.

```
View(available.packages())
View(installed.packages())
library()
.libPaths()
```

Similarly, [`data`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/data) with no arguments tells you which datasets are available on your machine.

```
data()
```

[`search`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/search) tells you which packages have been loaded.

```
search()
```

[`packageDescription`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/packageDescription) shows you the contents of a package's `DESCRIPTION` file. Likewise [`news`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/news) read the `NEWS` file.

```
packageDescription("utils")    
news(package = "ggplot2")
```

---

#### Getting help on variables

[`ls`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/ls) lists the variables in an environment.

```
ls()                 # global environment
ls(all.names = TRUE) # including names beginning with '.'
ls("package:sp")     # everything for the sp package
```

Most variables can be inspected using [`str`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/str) or [`summary`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/summary).

```
str(sleep)
summary(sleep)
```

[`ls.str`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/ls.str) is like a combination of `ls` and `str`.

```
ls.str()
ls.str("package:grDevices")
lsf.str("package:grDevices")  # only functions
```

For large variables (particularly data frames), the [`head`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/head) function is useful for displaying the first few rows.

```
head(sleep)
```

[`args`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/args) shows you the arguments for a function.

```
args(read.csv)
```

---

#### General learning about R

The [Info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) is a very comprehensive set of links to free R resources.

Many topics in R are documented via [`vignette`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/vignette)s, listed with [`browseVignettes`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/browseVignettes).

```
browseVignettes()
vignette("intro_sp", package = "sp")
```

By combining `vignette` with [`edit`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/edit), you can get its code chunks in an editor.

```
edit(vignette("intro_sp",package="sp"))
```

Comment: `news(package="sp")` (nothing for this particular package), `citation(package="sp")`

Comment: @hadley seems to be the same as `?sp` (btw, doesn't work on package `sp`, try on another one)

Comment: External links are discouraged since they sometimes get bought out and broken, as here. Personally, I almost always just write `?args` as code for the reader to type into their R session instead of giving a link.

Answer (score 13):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15290370/3924118) already gives you a very comprehensive list.

I would add that [`findFn("some search terms")`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sos/versions/2.0-0/topics/findFn) in package `sos` is extremely helpful, if you only have an idea/keywords of what you are looking for and don't already have a package or function in mind.

And also the [task views on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/): not really a search process but a great place to wander as you wonder.

Answer (score 2):

This thread contains many good suggestions. Let me add one more.

For finding which packages are loaded, plus extra goodies, [?sessionInfo](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/sessionInfo.html) is quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

`help(package="<package-name>")` where of course `<package-name>` is the name of the package you want help for.

Answer (score 1):

Often the same function name is used by several packages. To get help on a function from a specific package, use:

```
help(aggregate, package="stats")
help(aggregate, package="sp")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [RStudio IDE](https://www.rstudio.com) you can click on any function name and press <kbd>F1</kbd>, which will directly open the associated function help text in its pane. Like you would have called `help()` or `?fun()`.