# backtest simple strategies using R

Tags: r, xts, quantmod, quantstrat, blotter

I am looking to do simple backtesting that could properly keep track of pnl, rebalance portfolio, liquidate etc. I need it to do things a bit differently than `backtest`. That is, backtest splits things up by quntile and the sort. I would like a  more accounting system that I could pass a table with prices, give it positions and have it calculate pnl daily, exit on roll dates, etc. I understand `blotter` and `quantstrat` are two such packages but I'm having trouble finding documentation on them. Any help appreciated. I am including `xts` in the tags since the authors of that package seem to be quite knowledgeable on this topic.

Comment: Re: finding documentation for a package: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289995/get-help-for-r-package

Answer (score 1):

blotter and quantstrat are still in heavy development; you can download the code from https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=316.

quantstrat contains a lot of demos; the luxor demos for example in the demo directory should get you started.

HTH,

Jan Humme

Comment: Your setup must be different from mine because `demo("luxor.1.strategy")` gives an error that "luxor.include.R" cannot be found.  If I `setwd` to the demo directory of my checked out copy of the code, the next error is that there's no data in /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/quantstrat/extdata/GBPUSD.  Not to mention that both blotter and quantstrat still give Notes on install and running R CMD check on a build of either of those packages may make your computer explode.