# How to get help for plot function in sp package

Tags: r, plot, spatial

This may seem like a very easy issue, but I cannot find the answer 'out there' so it's time to ask the R community:

I'm looking for the help documentation for the function `sp::plot`.
Normally `help(plot)` would do the trick, but this does not work in this case as it's masked by `graphics::plot`. `help(sp::plot)` also fails. So is there no help file for this command or am I just looking in the wrong places. (Also I cannot find documentation for the function [online](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=%22sp::plot%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gl=uk&gws_rd=cr&ei=Ug6OUtzDAayQ7Abt-oHQDw), or in the [sp package documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/sp.pdf)).

This is a specific case not covered in the more general question
[Get help for R package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289995/get-help-for-r-package)

Comment: `?plot.sp` maybe, untested

Comment: Does it appear in `library(help=sp)`?  That will tell you if it's documented.  Also, as @rawr alludes, the specific method is likely documented.  What's the `class` of the object you're trying to plot?  If `sp` and it's an S3 method, then `?plot.sp` should work.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman it is an S4 methods. But internally it uses the S3 method `sp:::plot` (`sp:::plot.SpatialPolygons`,`sp:::plot.SpatialPoints`,`sp:::plot.Spatial`...). I think no easy way to get the help , but is is relatively simple to go through theses S3 methods...

Comment: Well,  what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft well I make a lot of maps in R and generally revert to ggplot2 partly due to its excellent documentation. It would be great to know what new arguments are available in sp::plot, for example can you add a scale bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can't find `?sp::plot` because that help page doesn't exist.

If in doubt, [browse the help pages](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sp/docs?tab=p).  In this case you can see that the only plot-related help pages in the `sp` package are `plot.SpatialGrid`, `plot.SpatialGridDataFrame` and `plot.SpatialPixelsDataFrame`.

It may have been helpful if the package authors had added `"plot.sp"` as an alias or additional help page so that search term led you to the correct pages.

Answer (score 1):

If author has provided documentation for the function , then you can always see if it's listed in `help(package='sp')`

Comment: @agstudy IMHO `help(package='sp')` is the way to check if the documentation exist or not.

Comment: Of course. But I think that the OP is already aware of this (AT best this can be a comment). But I admit that the OP (as already mentioned in the comment) is not clear in which problem he is trying to solve...