# extract predicted values from Partial least square regression in R

Tags: r

I have following:

```
library(pls)
pcr(price ~ X, 6, data=cars, validation="CV")
```

it works, but because I have a small dataset, I cannot divide in into training and test and therefore I want to perform cross-validation and then extract predicted data for AUC and accuracy. But I could not find how I can extract the predicted data.Which parameter is it?

Comment: Sorry, it should be per and it gives a lot as an output for help(pcr). What should I search for?

Comment: sorry, it is library(pls)

Comment: Where does `price` come from? I don't see that in the built-in `cars` data.

Comment: After `?pcr` look for information under "Values" to find out what the function returns. It will suggest you look at `?mvrCv` for more information on the `validation` result.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms: Okay, posted.

Comment: @AlexA. Thanks! You explained that better than I would have.

Comment: @Tonja I also recommend this [explanation of how to find help using R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289995/how-to-get-help-in-r/15290370#15290370).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fit a cross-validated principal component regression model with `pcr()` and the `validation=` argument, one of the components of the output list is called `validation`. This contains the results of the cross validation. This in turn is a list and it has a component called `pred`, which contains the cross-validated predictions.

An example adapted from `example("pcr")`:

```
sens.pcr <- pcr(sensory ~ chemical, data = oliveoil, validation = "CV")

sens.pcr$validation$pred
```

As an aside, it's generally a good idea to set your random seed immediately prior to performing cross validation to ensure reproducibility of your results.