# Using help.search or ??"something" returns: subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

I've been following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289995/how-to-get-help-in-r) answer about finding a function that you don't know the name of. But searching for something ends up with error. What is wrong?

```
> ??"dir"
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , "name", value = dDB[, 1]) : 
  subscript out of bounds

> help.search("directory")
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , "name", value = dDB[, 1]) : 
  subscript out of bounds

> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.1                         
year           2014                        
month          07                          
day            10                          
svn rev        66115                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
nickname       Sock it to Me           


> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] xtable_1.8-0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.1


> apropos('dir')
 [1] "dir"                     "dir.create"              "dirname"                
 [4] "getSrcDirectory"         "list.dirs"               ".rs.getProjectDirectory"
 [7] ".rs.lintDirectory"       ".rs.maxDirectoryList"    "substituteDirect"       
[10] "tempdir"

> getAnywhere('dir')
A single object matching ‘dir’ was found
It was found in the following places
  package:base
  namespace:base
with value

function (path = ".", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE, full.names = FALSE, 
    recursive = FALSE, ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, 
    no.. = FALSE) 
.Internal(list.files(path, pattern, all.files, full.names, recursive, 
    ignore.case, include.dirs, no..))
<bytecode: 0x3cbc750>
<environment: namespace:base>

> ?help.search

> find("help.search")
[1] "package:utils"
>
```

Comment: Could not replicate your error. Does it persist in a fresh R-session?

Comment: `sessionInfo()` is more helpful

Comment: @Heroka yes it is on fresh session.

Comment: Maybe update to the current R version (3.2.3) and try again.

Comment: do `apropos('dir')` and `getAnywhere('dir')` and `?help.search` work

Comment: results of `find("help.search")` ?

Comment: I've edited OP. PS: I'm using R-studio. Seems that `?help.search` is working.