# Having trouble with converting a column of data into factor in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert the origin column to a factor but not sure how to accomplish that.

[image: Picture of the data table]

Comment: What have you tried? `?factor` would be a good place to start.

Comment: I'm new to R. So I'm not quite sure how to start. a few helpful tips would be appreciated.

Comment: `?factor` isn't a good enough helpful tip? I actually think it's unlikely you'll get more of an answer here on SO; this is really basic and I'd guess you need more of an introduction to R than a Q/A site designed to answer specific questions can provide.

Comment: Before posting a question on SO, always search through existing questions. Chances are, someone else has already asked that very same question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a modified version of the `mtcars` dataset or something similar. As others have suggested, take a look at the `factor()` function.

Below is how to modify the column and variable `gear` to be a factor variable, which you can see using the `str()` function.

```
> str(mtcars)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
> mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear)
> str(mtcars)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: Factor w/ 3 levels "3","4","5": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

[Here's some general advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15290370/6873133) on getting help in R. Good luck.